# Unwanted line break in align

Tags: align

I have a formular in an `align`-environment, where I provide one manual line break, but it gets rendered with another line break after the one I added myself:

[image: 1]

Code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, dsfont}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathds{R}}

\begin{document}

\section*{1.1}
\begin{align*}
  B = \big\{ &\Vec{a} + \Vec{b} \in \RR^3 : \Vec{a} = (1, 0, z) \textrm{, mit} -1.5 \leq z \leq 1 \textrm{ } \wedge \\
  &\Vec{b} = (x, y, 0) \textrm{, mit } x, y \in \\R \wedge ||\Vec{b}|| \leq 2 \big\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Why is this additional second line break automatically added and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: It wasn't automatically added you have two line breaks in your code (`\\` and `\\R`).

Comment: Unrelated, don't use `||... ||` use `\lVert... \rVert` and I'd start the second line with the wedge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a math person, but the `\\R` is causing the line break. Were you trying to use `\RR`?

So the new code will be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, dsfont}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathds{R}}

\begin{document}

\section*{1.1}
\begin{align*}
  B = \big\{ &\Vec{a} + \Vec{b} \in \RR^3 : \Vec{a} = (1, 0, z) \textrm{, mit} -1.5 \leq z \leq 1 \textrm{ } \wedge \\
  &\Vec{b} = (x, y, 0) \textrm{, mit } x, y \in \RR %Change here
   \wedge ||\Vec{b}|| \leq 2 \big\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The corresponding output will be:

[image: Help_LaTeX]

Comment: Damn, I just didn't see it. Sometimes all you need is a second pair of eyes. Thank you :)